# How can I diff against a revision of a single file using only the default Git GUI tools?

Tags: git, user-interface, gitk

I want to view the history of a single file, and then compare a single revision from that history against the current version.

On the command line, this is easy:

1. Run:

   ```
   git log -- <filename>
   ```
2. Locate the version you want to compare,
3. Run:

   ```
   git diff <commitid> -- <filename>
   ```

But how can this be done using *only* the default Git gui tools, *git gui* and *gitk*?

I know of two methods using *gitk*, but they're both horribly clunky:

Either:

1. Select the New View option from the View menu,
2. Type in the full path to your file into the box labelled *Enter files and directories to include, one per line*,
3. Locate the version you want to compare by looking at the highlighted items in the top pane, and click on it to select it,
4. Right-click on the current version and select *Diff selected -> this*,

Or:

1. Select *Tree* in the bottom right-hand pane,
2. Locate the file you want to look at, right-click on it, and select *Highlight this only*,
3. Locate the version you want to compare by looking at the highlighted items in the top pane, and click on it to select it,
4. Right-click on the current version and select *Diff selected -> this*,
5. Click on the file in the bottom right-hand pane to jump to it in the diff output, or scroll manually.

Is there a better method than this?

Answer (score 1):

You can launch `gitk` from the command line and limit its scope to a single file.

You can also limit the output to a set of commits.

For example, to show the changes since `<commit>` that changed `path/to/file`, try:

```
gitk <commit>.. -- path/to/file
```

See the [`gitk` man page](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitk.html) for more details.

Comment: @timhenigan Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution that does not use the command line at *all*. I've edited the question to make this more clear.